# inherit background color from parent element instead of <body>

Tags: html, css, outlook

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color: grey" id="parent">
  <div style="background-color: red">
    content
  </div>
  <div style="margin: 10px; padding: 10px; background-color: yellow" id="child">margin and padding</div>
  <div style="background-color: aquamarine">
    aquamarine
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I render the page above in a browser, I get the following:
[image]

Notice that the background color (grey) of the `#parent` element is shown in the margin of the `#child` element.

However, if I use the same markup in a HTML email and open it in Outlook, I see this
[image]

In this case, the background color of the `<body>` image is shown in the margin of `#child`, instead of the background color of the parent element.

Is there a way to make Outlook behave in the same way as the browser?

Answer (score 2):

Outlook uses Word for rendering message bodies. In Word, two HTML elements that support a subset of the cascading style sheets properties are called out: DIV and P. Read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles:

- [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook (Part 1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338200(v=office.12))

Comment: If those pages have an answer to my question, could you include it in your answer, please?

Comment: You can replace div or p elements with another ones, for example, a table. It is up to you which way is to choose.

Comment: OK, but could you please show at least one possible solution in your answer?

Comment: I've explained why it happens in Outlook and why there is a difference between a browser and the desktop application. It is up to you which solution to introduce.

Comment: The problem is that all of the information is in the pages you've linked to, rather than your answer itself. If those links break, your answer is no longer useful